# How to change color of disabled html controls in IE8 using css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to change the color of input controls when they are disabled using the following css.

```
input[disabled='disabled']{
  color: #666;     
}
```

This works in most browsers, but not IE. I'm able to change any of the other style properties such as background-color, border-color, etc... just not color. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: #666; made me giggle a little :)

Comment: It wasn't meant to, It's just a good grey color for disabled controls.

Comment: See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486152/2906042 
It helped me)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Unfortunately if you use the disabled attribute, no matter what you try IE will just default the color of the text to Grey, with a weird white shadow...thing... yet all other styles will still work. :-/

Comment: Yea, but why? Is it using some non-standard filter style behind the scenes or something?

Comment: I almost voted this answer down, but I stopped myself. I was going to do it because I hated the answer; not because the answer was wrong. Voting up :p

Comment: I think this falls under the same category as the "Friendly Error Pages", M$ is just trying to help

Comment: Though this answer is 'correct', I think it would be useful to wiki-ize it and link to other SO questions that are useful at documenting what options are available to make the situation suck less. e.g. Forcing background color to white to make things more readable, using JS to change to read-only + force blur onFocus, JS to display a div instead of an input

Comment: been 4 years now, any improvement been made ?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem for `<select>` elements in **IE10** and found a solution that works for select elements only:

http://jsbin.com/ujapog/7/

There is a Microsoft pseudo-element that allows the text color to be modified:

```
select[disabled='disabled']::-ms-value {
    color: #000;
}
```

The rule must be on it's own, because otherwise other browsers will ignore the whole rule due to syntax error. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604(v=vs.85).aspx for other Internet Explorer only pseudo elements.

Edit: I think the rule should probably be `select[disabled]::-ms-value` but I don't have older IE versions in front of me to try it - re-edit this paragraph or add comment if that is an improvement.

Comment: I've tried on IE10 and IE11 and it works. Pay attention on disabled attribute. You can define it on different way. It could be `disabled`, `disabled=""`, `disabled="true"`, `disabled="disabled"`. Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE9.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to override styles for disable="disable" attribute. Here is my work around to fix this problem, note I am only selecting submit buttons in my case:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("input[type='submit'][disabled='disabled']").each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).attr("onclick", "javascript:return false;");
    });
}
```

example available: http://jsfiddle.net/0dr3jyLp/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with textarea "disabled" changing font color to gray.
I did a workaround by using "readonly" attribute instead of "disabled" attribute to textarea 
with below css

```
textarea[readonly] {
border:none; //for optional look
background-color:#000000; //Desired Background color        
color:#ffffff;// Desired text color
}
```

It worked for me like a charm!!, so I suggest to try this first before any other solution as it is easy to replace "disabled" with "readonly" without changing any other parts of code.

Comment: The best solution for me. Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I Know it's been a while since the creation of this topic, but i created this workaround, and well... It worked for me! ( Using IE 9 )

The only consequence is that you can't select the value of the input.

Using Javascript:

```
    if (input.addEventListener)
            input.addEventListener('focus', function(){input.blur()}, true)
    if (input.attachEvent)
            input.attachEvent("onfocus", function(){input.blur()})
```

Comment: That solution has the nasty usability side-effect of preventing the user being able to tab through a checkbox to the next control - yuck. Especially since you have made it break usability cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

I just made the whole background a light gray color, I think it more easily/quickly convey's that the box is disabled.

```
input[disabled]{
  background: #D4D4D4;     
}
```

Comment: Any idea on why this is being downvoted? It works in the latest version of IE, FF and Chrome...

Comment: Was the question not IE8 before?

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved the problem of "disabling" a control in IE w/o the ugly gray with a input control of type = checkbox was to leave it enabled and use a little javascript in the onclick event to prevent changes:

```
onclick='this.checked == true ? this.checked = false : this.checked = true;'
```

Comment: I think `onclick='return false;'` does the same thing but simpler

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Wayne, and three years later still no luck w/ IE9, but...

You could try lowering the `opacity` using CSS, it makes it more readable and helps with the whole disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

It is the solution that I found for this problem:

//if IE

inputElement.writeAttribute("unselectable", "on");

//Other browsers

inputElement.writeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

By using this trick, you can add style sheet to your input element that works in IE and other browsers on your not-editable input box.

Answer (score 0):

I mixed user1733926's and Hamid's solutions and I found an effective code for IE8, would be nice to know if it works in ie 9/10 as well (?).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("*[disabled='disabled']").each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).attr("unselectable", "on");
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post I decided to create a input that acts similarly to a disabled input box but was "readonly".

So I've made it so it wasn't able to be selected or tabbed to, or have a mouse cursor that gave the user the idea they can change or select the value.

Tested on IE8/9, Mozzila 18, Chrome 29

```
<input name="UserName" class="accountInputDisabled" id="UserName" type="text" readOnly="readonly" value="" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" onmousedown='return false;'/>


input.accountInputDisabled {
    border: 1px solid #BABABA !important;
    background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;    
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-input: disabled;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    cursor:not-allowed;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to overrride CSS use class based approach and play with events works perfectly

You can do one thing:

```
<button class="disabled" onmousedown="return checkDisable();">

function checkDisable() {
 if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) { return false; }
 }
```

http://navneetnagpal.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/ie-button-text-shadow-issue-in-case-of-disabled/

Answer (score 0):

Remove **disabled** attribute and use **readonly** attribute. Write required CSS for achieving the required result. This works in IE8 and IE9.

for e.g., for dark grey,

```
 input[readonly]{
   color: #333333;     
 }
```

Comment: The `readonly` attribute ignored if the value of the `type` attribute is `hidden`, `range`, `color`, `checkbox`, `radio`, `file` or `button` so it might not work as expected on all inputs

Answer (score 0):

Please check this CSS code.

```
input[type='button']:disabled, button:disabled
 {
    color:#933;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

or check this URL.
http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/uK8cL/13/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved in IE11.
If the problem still persists in IE11, check for the rendering engine IE is using.

Answer (score -2):

I came across this piece of code at stackoverflow which helped me take off disable css class using javascript.

```
$("#textboxtest").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("k-state-disabled");
```

Original thread can be found at [Applying k-state-disabled class to text inputs - Kendo UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491191/applying-k-state-disabled-class-to-text-inputs-kendo-ui)
Thought I should share!

Comment: You should comment whether or not this is Kendo specific. Not very helpful in its current composition

Answer (score -2):

Use this css, works for IE11:

```
input[disabled="disabled"], select[disabled="disabled"], textarea[disabled="disabled"] {
    opacity:0.99 !important;
    background:black;
    text-shadow:inherit;
    background-color:white;
    color:black
}
```