# Apply text color on disabled=true textbox

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to force a CSS Color on a "disabled=true" textbox?
By default, this attribute is removing the css font color and replacing it by a very light gray.

Thanks

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? Namely, what about IE6 and 7?

Comment: Use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to get it working in IE6/7 or only use it as a progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input[disabled='disabled'] {
  color:blue;
  }
```

[source](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/html/styling-disabled-buttons-disabled-text-boxes-in-css-404/)

Comment: @sisdog try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485642/how-do-you-style-disabled-textarea-in-ie8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with just using input[disabled='disabled'] was that it also includes checkboxes and radio buttons which I didn't want to handle quite the same way.  I found the following method worked for me...

```
INPUT[type=text][Disabled],
INPUT[type=search][Disabled],
INPUT[type=password][Disabled],
SELECT[Disabled] { color:blue;}
```