# How do you style disabled textarea in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

What rule do you need to enable styling of disabled elements in IE8? I have the code below now. It that works fine under IE7, but not on IE8. IE8 just give me plaint wihte background. Why?

```css
input[disabled], input:disabled, textarea[disabled], textarea[disabled="disabled"], textarea:disabled {
    background:#EBEBE4;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why bluefoot's answer was down voted? I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: he sure knows. He was the downvoter. Some explanation would be good.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### the :pseudo class in the selector is tripping up IE8!

you have to ungroup these selectors if you absolutely have to use those CSS3 **[pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#enableddisabled)**;

If there's a selector in the ruleset that IE8 doesn't understand it's ignoring the whole thing  - this is common in IE8 with CSS3 pseudo classes

e.g. If you separate them out and remove the pseudo `:disabled` parts of the selector completely - you'll see the first example below works for all, whereas the second one still works except for IE7

```
input[disabled], select[disabled], textarea[disabled] {background-color: #0f0;} /* lime green - works in IE7+ and modern browsers */

input[disabled="disabled"], select[disabled="disabled"], textarea[disabled="disabled"] {background-color:#ff0;} /* yellow -  IE8+ and modern browsers */
```

the color (as opposed to background-color) issue pointed at in another answer is not the cause of your issue, but it wouldn't help if you were also trying to change the color ;)

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to add a `disabled` class and style it:

```
input.disabled, textarea.disabled{ 
    background:#EBEBE4; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is really underrated. It also works really well for similar problems, like for instance if you would want  paired elements to show a hover-style simultainiously, when only one of them has a mouseover.