# Make TextArea Wicket non-editable

Tags: java, textarea, wicket

I need to make TextArea Wicket read-only. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just output the `readonly` attribute in the `<textarea>`, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTtH5/)?

If you need to do this inconditionally, just type it in your HTML, if it is conditional, add a `SimpleAttributeModifier` to the `TextArea`.

Answer (score 2):

Read this [http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setEnabled(boolean)](http://goo.gl/IukSr)

Comment: it does work but the textarea has been grayed out. How can we make the text clearer?

Comment: @Best you can style it with CSS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485642/how-do-you-style-disabled-textarea-in-ie8