# Using :disabled in CSS disabled button style b0rks IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have created a custom CSS button class called `linkbutton`.  It is intended to work on both `a` and `input` as sometimes calls to action will be links and other times they will be real submit buttons.  In this case an anchor setup like so doesn't render properly

```
<a href="" class="linkbutton disabled" id="folderManagementAdd">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add Sub Folder</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.linkbutton.disabled, input[disabled=disabled].linkbutton, input:disabled.linkbutton
{
    color: #ccc;
}

    .linkbutton.disabled:hover, input[disabled=disabled].linkbutton:hover, input:disabled.linkbutton:hover
    {
        color: #ccc;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: 1px solid gainsboro;
        cursor: default;
    }
```

In IE8 this only works when I dont use the `input:disabled` section at the end (which I need for real browsers).  Is there something I can do to get around this? I really dont want to specify the CSS twice!

Comment: Wouldn't `input[disabled].linkbutton:hover` cover all* browser scenarios? (*) the majority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 ignores the rule, since it doesn't understand `:disabled`.

A little research goes a long way: [How do you style disabled textarea in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485642/how-do-you-style-disabled-textarea-in-ie8)

Comment: Im sure I tried exactly that and it didn't work before, it works though now cheers