# IE8 fails to properly style font-awesome icon after applying css class

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

http://jsfiddle.net/7Q7ht/10/

```
<a class="edit linkButton" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Enable rack editing">
    <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
    Edit
</a>

$(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        $('.linkButton').addClass('disabled');

    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function(){

        $('.linkButton').removeClass('disabled');

    }, 4000);
});

a.linkButton {
    color: red;
}

a.linkButton:hover {
    color: blue;
}

a.linkButton.disabled {
    color: gray;
}
```

Fairly simple code. Works fine in modern browsers. Under IE8 when I add the disabled class to linkButton, the icon-pencil span continues to be painted red, not gray. Is there a simple fix for this sort of thing?

Here's a picture, don't worry about the icon not showing up, I just don't have the font loaded: [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me in IE8, it turns from red to gray, then red again. That's the same thing it does in Chrome.

You probably know that Microsoft says the `disabled` CSS3 pseudo-class [only works in IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127307(v=vs.85).aspx) and up. Otherwise, the question [How do you style disabled textarea in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485642/how-do-you-style-disabled-textarea-in-ie8) suggests some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not redraw pseudo-elements without change the content.

You can solve that problem with that hack...

```
a.linkButton {
    color: red;

    .icon-pencil {
        content: "\F040 "
    }
}

a.linkButton:hover {
    color: blue;

    .icon-pencil {
        content: "\F040 "
    }
}

a.linkButton.disabled {
    color: gray;

    .icon-pencil {
        content: "\F040 "
    }
}
```

The thing is: IE8 does not redraw pseudo-elements like FontAwesome icons without a change on the content. So you need to force that change of content.

The way I did that was retrieving the content set by FontAwesome and adding a space. Unfortunately I only could do that repeating the same code for each selector that I need change the style.