# Extremely weird behaviour with disabled elements in IE (localhost vs web server)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have disabled elements on my page. When I run my app in VS2012, my disabled elements are looking like I want in IE (8-10) (not Chrome but I'll look at that later):

[image]

Notice the burgundy text. Now, I deploy to my web server. All the CSS is present and now the text is gray:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
input[disabled] {
             border: 1px solid #999;
             color:#933 !important;
             background-color:#c1c1c1;
}
```

Here's how I'm setting my input to disabled

```
      $('#btnRemovePacks').prop('disabled', true);
```

Why does the CSS work when I'm running in localhost and not when I deploy to my web server?

Comment: You're probably in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Honestly im not. Everyone's IE looks the same. Ive looked at this on multiple computers

Comment: As someone who's not very familiar with VS2012, does running the app through it add any additional libraries (whether js or css) when previewing? Another idea... try viewing the IE Developer Tools for both versions and see exactly which IE mode is being used. It's possible the webserver (or your localhost server) is configured to force a certain compatibility mode using http headers.

Comment: @Daniel...as far as I know, no it doesn't. I've used VS2012 for a year

Comment: Does IE8 even catch `[disabled]`? (9 and 10 should, though.)

Comment: One part of the puzzle is [How do you style disabled textarea in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5485642)