# How can I fully override Chromium disabled input field colours?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, w3c, chromium

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wCFBw/25/

[image]

```
input {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This is black" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Why this is not black?" />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't *know* why that happens, but I *suspect* WebKit is trying to be smart with respect to letting the user know the `<input>` is disabled.

You can workaround this by also using the [`-webkit-text-fill-color` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266--webkit-text-fill-color):

```
input.black {
    color: black;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: black
}
```

Please, make sure you're setting the colour to something that makes it apparent that the `<input>` is disabled.

Here's your demo, modified with the new property: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wCFBw/38/

Comment: You should have earned the l33t badge for this answer.

Comment: This seems to be text-fill-color and text-stroke CSS3 stuff

Comment: No problem! This property isn't really CSS3 as such; it's a WebKit-only proprietary property. According to the link in my answer, it's `Available in Safari 3.0 and later`, so it's been around for a while.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Any idea how to make this work in IE8? (The color is just grey...)

Comment: @philfreo: There doesn't seem to be a *good* way, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css - you *can* set the input to `readonly` instead, but that has other consequences (such as with `readonly`, the `input` will be sent to the server on submit, but with `disabled`, it won't be): http://jsfiddle.net/wCFBw/40/

Comment: @thirtydot is there anyway to change the background colour instead of font-colour for highlighting purpose ?

Comment: `-webkit-text-fill-color: currentcolor` Thanks for the link to the API.