# How to change the color of disabled input textbox text color in ie9 using css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have already checked the following 
[How to change color of disabled html controls in IE8 using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css)
[Change the font color of disabled input text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073754/change-the-font-color-of-disabled-input-text-box)

Is there anyway to change the font color in ie9?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled attribute Css doesn't work on IE older versions. but now IE 11 support it.

Here is the Demo link. [`http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/NpHn6/4/`](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/NpHn6/4/)

I used this CSS line.

```
input[type="text"]:disabled{color:red;}
```