# Set font color of disabled text input field

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011

I know that this topic exist more than once, but I need a clear solution.

Has someone an idea to set the font color of disabled fields for IE < 10.

If possible, without replacing the "disabled" property with the "read-only" property. 
The reason is, I work with CRM 2011 software and I cannot predict the effects if I do that.

Perhaps, someone can tell me whats happen if I remove the "disabled" property with JS and I still cannot write into the textbox.

JavaScript solutions are welcome.

Best regards

Comment: Yes but there is still the postback problem. Fields with "read-only" property will send to the server..

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot change color of disabled inputs in IE
Refer [How to change font-color for disabled input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186989/how-to-change-font-color-for-disabled-input)

You either can make that input as readonly to do it but you will have to suffer consequence as  with readonly, the input will be sent to the server on submit, but with disabled, it won't be.

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602070/changing-font-colour-in-textboxes-in-ie-which-are-disabled) for more information

Comment: You can always force the submit of disabled fields to CRM using the setSubmitMode

Answer (score -2):

Well css pseudo-class :disabled should work for you.

```
input[type="submit"]:disabled {

}
```