# IE8 issue in displaying CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

H, I am new to browser compatibility issue debugging.

I have following html segment:

```
<div class="settings_content">
 ...
 ...

 <div class="field">
    <input name="name" maxlength="256" type="text" size="32" value="" class="noBdr" disabled="">
 </div>
```

and I have a corresponding CSS for the input field:

```
 .settings_content input
 {
    color: #505050;
 }
```

in browser Chrome, IE10, IE9, the text indicated by that "input" tag will all be rendered correctly as black. However, if I test it in IE8, the text will still be shown, but the color will turn into grey.

I don't think this is a CSS issue but more of a cross-browser issue. Could experts give me some hints on where to debug? Thanks!

Comment: I see that the input also contains a class ".noBdr". Is that class positioned in the css above or below the ".settings_content input"?

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge, yes, there is a class for ".noBrd" in css, they are actually in two different CSS, the ".noBrd" css is an overriding css, which is supposed to override the base.css in which the ".settings_content input" is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the color of a disabled input in Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9. If it were a regular input, your styles would have applied even without the `!important` part suggested in the previous answer. 
For more info on the topic consider reading [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186989/how-to-change-font-color-for-disabled-input).

**EDIT:**
It works in IE10 though.
You can open [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcNsd/) in IE to check.

Comment: the !important method doesn't work in IE8. Do you have any suggestions or do I have to make it a regular input?

Comment: @Kevin, no methods will allow you to do that. It is a browser feature. a) you either _undisable_ the input (but I assume it is done for a reason, so be careful) b) you accept that lucky IE8 users will be happy to see the grey color of an input (not your needed color) - aka "graceful degradation"

Answer (score 1):

Try using `!important`

Like this:

```
.settings_content input
 {
    color: #505050 !important;
 }
```

This might solve your problem...

**OR**

Use inline css like:-

```
<input /**********/ style="color: #505050 !important;" />
```

**OR**

Use some [Browser Hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) for this...