# How to change Text color of a disabled button in IE?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to change the text color of a disabled button in IE. With below code ,the text color is appropriate in Firefox/Chrome but no effect in IE :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
button[disabled] {
    color:#933;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="submit" disabled="disabled">Sample Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong here or any alternate ways to do it will be helpful.

Comment: Check this may be it'll help you to Change Color of Disable


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186989/how-to-change-font-color-for-disabled-input

Comment: use the ie css with  the \0/   or with *   like    color:red\0/;  or  *color:red; and which version of ie useing let me know

Answer (score 2):

or you can try this piece of code of javascript

```
 $('input:button[disabled=true],input:submit[disabled=true]').each(function() {  
            $(this).addClass("commandExButtonDisabled");  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

please use this CSS Code.

```
input[type='button']:disabled, button:disabled
{
    color:#933;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Regards,
Kheema

Answer (score 1):

The IE text color for the disabled button can’t be changed. You can wrap into another element or change the background or the border.