# Make TextArea Disabled in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I want to make Textarea Disable (Grayed out) in my JS Method

```
function myfun(status){

if(status=='Yes'){
    $('input[id$="txtareaID"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
}
```

The above code is not working for this.

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well please.

Comment: if you are looking for readonly a text area then do something like this     $("#idoftextarea").attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 2):

You should use `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$('input[id$="txtareaID"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2):

If your selector is correct, than you need only to change `attr` to `prop`:

```
function myfun(status){
   if(status === 'Yes'){ // more suitable for comparing
       $('input[id$="txtareaID"]').prop('disabled',true); 
   }
}
```

Related post:
[Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Considering textarea as

```
<textarea id='txt'>Something</textarea>
```

Using jQuery, you can achieve like this

```
$("#txt").attr('disabled', true);
```

Using plain javascript

```
document.getElementById("txt").disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with CSS not JS. As far I can tell your code is working, but there's no way of changing this specific style. You could try workarounds: [Change Font Color For Disabled Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186989/how-to-change-font-color-for-disabled-input)

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>` is what you should be looking for not the `<input>` tag with id = `textareaid`.

```
$('input[id$="txtareaID"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

change the above code to the below one and see the magic by clicking the link at the bottom.

```
$('textarea[id$="txtareaID"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5s9ge7d6/1/

Answer (score 0):

none of the below answers worked.
Then I found something amazing trick  which solved my problem ---
Here it is --- JUST REMOVE "input" word from that line in if block -

**WORKED CODE :**

```
function myfun(status){

if(status=='Yes'){
    $('[id$="txtareaID"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
}
```

**Previous CODE :**

```
 function myfun(status){

    if(status=='Yes'){
        $('input[id$="txtareaID"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
        $('input[id$="txtareaID"]').prop('disabled',true); //Didn't worked either
    }
```