# Controls not grey out in Chrome but they does in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser

I am disabling a sortable using this line of code:

```
$(".sorrtlist").sortable('enable');
```

In IE they are greying out but not in Chrome, what should I do ?

I can't use ('disabled', 'disabled'); as sortable doesn't support it.

**Edit**
I know chrome doesn't like greying out and also looked at questions you are claiming to be duplicates but NON of questions asking greying out for `".sortable"`

Comment: @Arran non of questions tell me how to grey out "sortable" do they ?

Comment: Chrome doesn't like greying out, see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412671/styling-of-disabled-input-elements-discrepancy-between-chrome-and-firefox). Also to reproduce you don't need jQuery, ASP.NET or JavaScript: test this and see if it shows the correct result: `<html><body><input type="text" disabled="disabled" /></body></html>`. Show screenshots to compare expected and actual results.

Comment: @CodeCaster I already read the other questions you guys are giving link to and I can't use ('disbaled', 'disabled') on .sortable, can I ?

Comment: _"NON of questions asking greying out for ".sortable""_ - do you expect an answer for each unique question to exist on this site? Look at methods used, implement them your own way. If your question is _"How do I show a .sortable element as disabled"_, then ask that.

Comment: @CodeCaster what ELSE DID I ASKED ? I am asking about .sortable and it not already been asked any where else, if you had argument with your wife don't take it OUT ON ME PLEASE !

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry to hear that, I didn't knew, anyway I fixed the issue by putting my sortable into a div giving it a class name and then greying out class using fadeout

Comment: Don't be, it wasn't true, I was just pointing out that replies like that may be found offensive. If I say I don't understand the question, that means you can do something to help more people understand it, which will help in getting a solution faster. But nice you got it solved. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jquery 1.6+ try prop.  for more info see this answer. [attr Not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048022/jquery-attrdisabled-disabled-not-working-in-chrome)

```
$('.class :input').prop('disabled',true);
```

if still problem persists. set  CSS as mentioned in this [disabled issue in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412671/styling-of-disabled-input-elements-discrepancy-between-chrome-and-firefox)

```
 -webkit-text-fill-color: black
```