# combine classes ie8 doesn't work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've got the following CSS:

```
.class1,
.class2:hover,
.class3:disabled { color:red; }
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9 and IE7.
Only browser that doesn't support this is IE8.

Is there a way to make it work?

Tnx

Comment: Disabled pseudo-class and IE8 are incompatible, hover is buggy and inconsistent at best so the only reliable class that IE7 & IE8 would pick up is .class1, but would bounce over the rule entirely because of the incompatibilities of the other pseudo classes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css

Comment: @Daniel that's not entirely true, Hover works fine in IE8 with the only flaw of elements with negative z-index giving trouble on manipulation which i consider seldom enough to ignore that. Nonetheless, both IE7 and IE8 recognize the hover pseudoclass. The disable pseudoclass causes the problem.

Comment: @Christoph - I stand corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 8 does not support the pseudoclass [`:disabled`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled) (neither does IE7) altogether. Multiple classes and `:hover` are supported.

Unlike IE7, IE8 behaves correctly according to [§4.1.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets) and ignores the entire rule due to the fact that it cannot interpret one of the selectors.

Comment: Tnx. That solved my problem.
Although something weird. It did work in IE7.
The disabled didnt work in IE7, but the css line did.

Comment: Yes, this is because IE7 ignores §4.1.7 of the CSS2.1 Spec I mentioned in my answer and uses the style-rule nonetheless, although according to standard it should not. IE8 behaves correctly on that behalf.