# JQM, CSS: How to change disabled fields css?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, disabled-input

I have simple JQuery Mobile form where I have textfields that could be disabled or enabled depending on some conditions. 
Normal enabled textfield looks like this:

[image: enabled]

and disabled looks like that:

[image: disabled]

I'd like to make the text in the disabled field a bit more readable. How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCityPostal" AssociatedControlID="txtCityPostal" runat="server"
       Text="City"></asp:Label>                        
<div class="clear">
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCityPostal" runat="server">
```

**Solution**

As suggested below I'm now using the following CSS:

```
input.regTxt:disabled {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I've added `CssClass="regTxt"` to all my text fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:disabled` selector. For example:

```
input:disabled {
    color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

See this Fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A9CN8/

[All notable modern browser support :disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled), but for Internet Explorer 8 and below you are out of luck: [for those browsers you cannot change the look of disabled controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:disabled`

```
input[type="text"]:disabled { 
   /* This may lack browser support so go for the next selector*/
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LuUP4/)

Or you can also use `element[attr=val]` selector

```
input[type="text"][disabled="disabled"] {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LuUP4/1/)

Comment: Can you specify: for which browsers the latter is a better option?

Comment: Yeah I figured that out too, but I'm not sure if the latter option is any better in practice. I mean: which browsers would benefit from the latter selector type?

Comment: @jsalonen It's completely normal practice, it's no hack

Comment: I'll post and edit with jsfiddle shortly, your examples would work in normal situation, but here I'm using JQuery Mobile and it seems that it is not working.

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks for your answer, but I'll select the jasalonen's one since he has less rep than you. +1

Comment: @AntonBelev hehe no issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Use  the `:disabled` selector

```
input:disabled {
    color: your_color;
}
```