# Anchor tag when disabled, the text turns gray in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, disabled-control

I am having a anchor tag whose text is turning gray when disabled. I know this the default IE treatment of anything that is disabled.

I am trying to overwrite the color of the anchor tag with the below mentioned CSS using `a[disabled=""]` and a[disabled="disabled"]. However both classes are not working.

```
<a href="www.google.com" disabled="">Google</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:link, a:active, a:visited {
color: blue !important;
display: block;
font: bold 12px;
padding-left: 5px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
line-height: 35px;
}

a.[disabled=""] , a[disabled="disabled"]
{
color: blue !important;
cursor: default;
}
```

Another method which I tried, is using a JQuery to add inline style.

```
if ($("a").attr('disabled', "")) {
  $("a").css({ "color": "blue" })
}
```

None of the above is working. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css), you're out of luck.

Comment: Although it may not solve you issue, you do have a syntax error in one of your CSS selectors. Change `a.[disabled=""] , a[disabled="disabled"]` to `a[disabled]`. The mistake you made was adding an accidental period, causing it not to select the tag. By only having the disabled attribute in the selector, the CSS will select the a tag as long as the *disabled* attribute exists on the `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks for that. That was an issue while copy pasting the code.

Comment: I guess You cant override that IE Behaviour using CSS or Javascript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geekonweb/ggyhs/  look at this fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

As per the specs, the `a` element does not have a `disabled` attribute! It is not an element that can be disabled.

As per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:

> ```
> interface HTMLAnchorElement : HTMLElement {
>   attribute DOMString target;
>   attribute DOMString download;
>   [PutForwards=value] attribute DOMSettableTokenList ping;
>   attribute DOMString rel;
>   readonly attribute DOMTokenList relList;
>   attribute DOMString hreflang;
>   attribute DOMString type;
>
>   attribute DOMString text;
>
>   // also has obsolete members
> };
> ```

And, as per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#disabled-elements:

> An element is said to be **actually disabled** if it is one of the following:
>
> - a `button` element that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)
> - an `input` element that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)
> - a `select` element that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)
> - a `textarea` element that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)
> - an `optgroup` element that has a `disabled` attribute
> - an `option` element that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#concept-option-disabled)
> - a `fieldset` element that is a [disabled fieldset](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#concept-fieldset-disabled)
> - a [form-associated custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-element) that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)

If you find yourself trying to `disable` an anchor (`a`), you are doing it wrong.

If you really need to indicate that an `a` is disabled and should not respond to the interactions with it, then you may use `pointer-events` css property to make it so. (*pointer-events property is supported by all modern browsers, but not by IE < 11*)

***Example Snippet***:

```css
a.disabled { 
    pointer-events: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,128,0.5);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">this is a normal link</a> | <a href="#" class="disabled">this appears to be disabled</a>
```

---

##Edit:

Per your comment, if you need to support older version of IE, then you could:

1. Use jQuery to prevent the default behaviour (`e.preventDefault()`), or
2. Remove the `href` attribute and style such `a` (without `href`) appropriately.

The example below, shows all three options (including the one given earlier):

***Example Snippet 2***:

```js
$("a.disabled").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
a.disabled { 
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.5);
}
a:not([href]) {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">this is a normal link</a> | 
<a>this is a disabled link</a> | 
<a href="http://example.com" class="disabled">this appears to be disabled</a>
```

Comment: I agree with you. But `pointer-events: none;` does not work for IE. Any other alternative?

Comment: @Archana: I have edited the answer and have added two more options for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set it, using either CSS or jQuery. Both your syntax for CSS and jQuery are incorrect.

```js
$('a[disabled]').css('color', 'blue');
```

```css
a[disabled]{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" disabled="disabled">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks to @Abhitalks for guiding on the specs.
Combining his hint, I have come up with a solution for my question:

1) I am adding a class 'disabled' to the anchor element whenever I want to disable it:

```
$("a").addClass("disabled");
```

2) Since `pointer-events: none;` does not work for IE, I have the below snippet that can do out work across all browsers:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

3) Define a class in CSS for the 'disabled' class:

```
a.disabled {
 color:red;
}
```

There you go! We are done!

P.S: Please Note! If you would like to disable the `preventDefault()`, below code to be used:

```
$("a").unbind('click');
```