# how to apply css on textbox for ie9

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply color:#000 on disabled textbox inwhich text is being displayed as part of the info.
(problem: text appearing in textbox is faded default)
Any suggestion??

[please see this picture coming in ie9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E55Jz.png)

Comment: Add a picture to make your example easier to get.

Comment: hi, please check the picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of disabled html controls in IE8 using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411044/how-to-change-color-of-disabled-html-controls-in-ie8-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

I think what the question is trying to say is that this:

```
<textarea disabled="disabled" style="color:#000  ;">Hello</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS attribute selector for better solution. Check out this example -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Attribute Selector Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
    input[disabled]{
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
</head> 
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Disabled Input">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To know how attribute selector works you can check out this page - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-attribute-selectors.php

Also if you want to apply the style only in IE this page will be helpful to you -
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-define-style-sheet-only-for-internet-explorer.php